# OpenCV videowrite doesn't write video

Tags: python, opencv, video

I used the following page from `OpenCV 3.0.0` tutorial: [Tutorial in docs](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video)

When I tried to use the example that saves videos, it doesn't work.

It displays the content from the webcam, and also creates a file called `output.avi`, but when I checked the size of `ouput.avi`, it was zero bytes.

I also tried using different codecs, like `YUY2`.

I use `Python 2.7.8` and `OpenCV 3.0.0`
and `Windows 8.1`

Comment: If anyone has a similar issue and is writing black and white image, you need to specify that the image is not in colour: `out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0,(int(cap.get(3)),int(cap.get(4))), False)`

Answer (score 40):

I had the same problem and I solved it by specifying the video output resolution to exactly the same as input:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')
...
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0,(int(cap.get(3)),int(cap.get(4))))
```

Of course make sure you got `ffmpeg` installed and working.

Comment: Even if the input is from converted PIL image, make sure the size is the same!

Answer (score 28):

I was struggling with this problem for a few hours then I realized that I had typed the image's shape wrong.

It is **`(width, height)`**, ie:

```py
(image.shape[1], image.shape[0])
```

and not

```py
(image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
```

This is how my working code looks like finally... (I am on a Windows machine):

```py
video_path = FILENAME + '.avi'
size = images[0].shape[1], images[0].shape[0] ## <<<--- NOTICE THIS
video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_path,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 60, size)  

for img in images:  
    video.write(img)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. For me the problem is, that just DIVX as fourcc works.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wish OpenCV raised an exception when it got a frame that didn't match the dims. That would have saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 22):

Replacing:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
```

With:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
```

Worked for me...

More generally:

Look up the fourcc code of the video compression format you're after [here](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php), and whatever the code is - for instance 'FMP4' for FFMpeg - plug it in in the following manner:

```
cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('F','M','P','4')
```

Comment: Actually, `(*'XVID')` is the same as `('X', 'V', 'I', 'D')`

Take a look at https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

Comment: Yes,  cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G') is work. I use opencv 4.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you are using the correct fourcc 4-byte code.  The example on the tutorial has:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
```

This `XVID` code may only work for linux.  The documentation above the example states (in the tutorial):
"In Windows: DIVX (More to be tested and added)."  So if you haven't, try replacing the fourcc line above with:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
```

I use `cv2.VideoWriter` on linux quite often and it always works.  So if the above doesn't work you can always try it on a linux vm.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work. DIVX doesn't work for me. Thanks for helping.

Comment: CV2 makes use of ffmpeg.  It could be that cv2 is not finding the application.

Comment: I looked through my code and found that I have this line: fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('X', 'V', 'I', 'D').  This is for a Linux vm but you could make appropriate changes and try it.  I don't know where I originally found this code but it works for me.

Comment: It doesn't work on Linux, Debian Stretch stable. If yes for you, then you are a lucky man. For me it has created the output file once properly, once with 0 bytes length and 500-times no file was created (no error reported; command timing as if all works excellent) :(((

Comment: @mirek I just tested it on ubuntu 16.04 with opencv3 installed and it is working for me.  I tested with color image frames so as posted above I don't specify the `isColor` flag, however you may want to verify that you have this correctly set to True/False, as needed.  This won't give an exception if you have it set incorrectly, you just get an "un-playable" video.  If this doesn't help it may be that you need to install ffmpeg or alternative on your machine.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I thought the codec was an obstacle but it wasn't. Instead, adjusting the dimensions being consumed by videoWriter() did the trick:

```
(ok, frame) = cv2.VideoCapture(videoPath).read()

 fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
 out = cv2.VideoWriter(output, fourcc, 10.0, (1280, 720))
```

(1280,720) was used because frame.shape from my video outputs (1280, 720, 3). It made avi to mp4 and vice versa possible. Didn't have to worry about reconciling the codec.

Answer (score 7):

Check the resolution of your images!
I was trying with odd-shaped images (1284x709) and ended up with unreadable videos of 1k in size. After resizing my image to the closest 'common' resolution: 
`image = cv2.resize(image, (1280,720))`,
it worked just fine.

Comment: Also, check for an error message. I had on my jupyter notebook: OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x5634504d/'MP4V' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v', and by using the exact 4 letters as suggested (mp4v), respecting the case, the message disappeared.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect there are a lot of reasons video writing fails silently, and in my case, my frame was a composite of a 3 channel image and a 4 channel image (transparent overlay). Converting the end result to BGR format as follows allowed the video to save successfully.

```
width = 1280
height = 720
FPS = 30
fourcc = VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')
video = VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, float(FPS), (width, height))
for img in images:
  frame = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
  video.write(frame)
video.release()
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be a problem with the codec you're using.

Have you tried:

`cv.CV_FOURCC('i', 'Y', 'U', 'V')`

This one worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

On windows 7 and using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 2.4.8, I experienced the fact that if the file NAME is `"output.mpg"` would not write.

I solved it by changing to `"output.avi"`.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue. I am using OpenCV in C++, but I believe you can still pass `-1` instead of choosing the codec so you can have a drop down menu of the available codecs even in python. From there I tried all different codecs and just like Leonard Zhou, the `IYUV` codec was the one that worked for me. Also note that it was the only one that worked even though I could use XVID just fine on another machine with the same code and same codec installer.

**EDIT:**
What I suggested worked as a patch, the main issue was solved on my end by adding the `opencv_ffmpeg` dll in the executable's folder.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the Video writer size to my screen resolution size and it worked.

here is the solution.

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 5.0, (1920, 1080))
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after I assigned the actual frame size and not what I thought the size was:

```py
ret, frame = cap.read()
height, width, channels = frame.shape
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"DIVX")
out=cv2.VideoWriter('new.avi',codec ,20.0,(width, height))
```

And put `out.write(frame)` inside the while loop before `cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)`.

Comment: On my system, only 'DIVX' works whereas the encoding on the opencv documentation examples, 'M', 'J', 'P', 'G', just silently writes no file. I wish there was a way to verify the codec so that my code is more safely portable.

Answer (score 1):

After trying hours to find the error, I finally found it. So here are some things to keep in mind. (For Linux users particularly)

1. Use this codec ("MJPG").

   ```
   cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
   ```
2. Do not forget to write the Boolean value as final argument (True for RGB and False for GrayScale) in

   ```
   cv2.VideoWriter(path, fourcc, float(frameRate), frameSize, True)
   ```
3. The argument, `frameSize` required by `cv2.VideoWriter`  is a tuple of form `(width, height)` and not `(height, width)` which is the shape of image array if you open the image using `cv2.read` or `Image.open`. So don't forget to invert it.

Answer (score 0):

To state the obvious, make sure you're giving not only a correct path, but also a video name.
i.e. `path/'video.avi'` and not just `path/`. It will fail silently otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am resizing the image, but saving video with original size instead of new size.

Answer (score 0):

The above methods work only for RGB frames/images. Incase you are trying to write a grayscale image, pass a parameter `0` to the `VideoWriter()`:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 30, size, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue that the video file was being created without any errors but it won't run and had a size of few KBs. Here's how I resolved it;

1. Make sure you have passed FPS argument in float value.
2. The output resolution needs to be same as of input video resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the folder did not exists. It fails silently .

```
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(self.video_output_path_temp), exist_ok=True)
out = cv2.VideoWriter(self.video_output_path_temp, fourcc, frame_rate, (screen_width, screen_height))
```

Answer (score 0):

Install ffmpeg using

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried by creating its exe using `pyinstaller Recorder.py` it worked for me.

Remember before using `pyinstaller` you have to `pip install pyinstaller`.