# Why is python screen recorder not creating .avi file?

Tags: python, opencv, screenshot, avi, screen-recording

I'm trying to make python screen recorder that outputs AVI file. The loop should stop after pressing 'q' but that doesn't work. When I interrupt the program with Ctrl + C, it doesn't output anything either. I'm using Mac OS.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui

SCREEN_SIZE = (1440, 900)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output2.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (SCREEN_SIZE))

while True:
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    frame = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow("screenshot", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
out.release()
```

I would very much appreciate your advice ;)

Comment: `assert out.isOpened()`

Comment: I think that the resolution of `img` that returned by `pyautogui.screenshot()` is not 1440x900. Try `img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0, 0, SCREEN_SIZE[0], SCREEN_SIZE[1]))`.

Answer (score 2):

Here ([OpenCV videowrite doesn't write video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320976/opencv-videowrite-doesnt-write-video/62546737)) i found the most commont problem is that it doesn't save if the resolution is wrong.

To be sure you are using the right resolution from your screen use `SCREEN_SIZE = pyautogui.size()`

The complete code would be:

```py
import cv2 as cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui

SCREEN_SIZE = pyautogui.size() # changed this line

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output2.avi", fourcc, 20.0, SCREEN_SIZE)

while True:
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    frame = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow("screenshot", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
out.release()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) But the only thing that worked for me was changing (*"XVID") to ('F','M','P','4'). Now it's outputing AVI but quicktime player still can't open it....